# Unable to refresh the gridview in android using notify dataset changed

Tags: android, gridview

I am creating an android application in which there is a scenario where i have to add new items to the grid i am using an layout inflater to add new items to the grid the items gets added to the database sucessfully but the grid view is not refreshed once the item is added i have used notify dataset changed but it is not working can anyone tell me what i have to change in the existing code

Activity for the gridview:

```
listet = databaseHandlerOtherchgs.getAllproducttitle();
listet.add(new OtherChargesType("Plucking", bitMapData));
listet.add(new OtherChargesType("Loading", bitMaploading));
listet.add(new OtherChargesType("Add New", bitMapaddnew));

listcharges = new ArrayList<CustomizedCharge>());

adapter = new OtherChargesGridAdpater(SinglePageTransaction.this, listet);
gv.setAdapter(adapter);
gv.setExpanded(true);
```

GridAdapter:

```
public class OtherChargesGridAdpater extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<OtherChargesType> otherchargestypes;
    DatabaseHandlerOtherChgs databaseHandlerOtherchgs;

    public OtherChargesGridAdpater(Activity activity, List<OtherChargesType> otherchargestypes) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.otherchargestypes = otherchargestypes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return otherchargestypes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return otherchargestypes.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        if (convertview == null) {
            convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_othercharges_griditem, null);
        }
        OtherChargesType m = otherchargestypes.get(position);
        byte[] outImage = m.getImage();
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
        final Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        ImageView otherimages = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        final TextView typename = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        databaseHandlerOtherchgs=new DatabaseHandlerOtherChgs(activity);

        // getting movie data for the row


        typename.setText(m.getTypename());
        otherimages.setImageBitmap(theImage);
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertview;
    }

    public void updatedata(){
        DatabaseHandlerOtherChgs databaseHandlerOtherChgs =new DatabaseHandlerOtherChgs(activity);
        databaseHandlerOtherChgs.getAllproducttitle();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's you intention with this? It looks like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Can't you just use a String extra for the intent and then re-populate the EditText in your onCreate?

Comment: you can try with onSaveInstanceState

Comment: you can use onSaveInstanceState or sharedpreferences... before refresh save all data to sharedpreferences and after refresh get data from sharedpreferences and show it.

Comment: for grid refresh use  adapter.notifyDataChanged(); and grid.setAdapter(adapter); Or call your adapter onResume Method in activity

Answer (score 1):

Use This code in Activity.. This code store your data.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
outState.putString("MSG", "This is my message to be reloaded");
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

In Oncreate Method put this code

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    String str= savedInstanceState.getString("MSG");
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And for refresh your activity use follow code

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Make Changes as per your requirement.